# Sample an index of a maximal number in an array, with a probability of 1/(number of maximal numbers)

Tags: algorithm

This is one of the recent interview question that I faced. Program to return the index of the maximum number in the array [ To Note : the array may or may not contain multiple copies of maximum number ] such that each index ( which contains the maximum numbers ) have the probability of 1/no of max numbers to be returned.

Examples:

- [-1 3 2 3 3], each of positions [1,3,4] have the probability 1/3 to be returned (the three 3s)
- [ 2 4 6 6 3 1 6 6 ], each of [2,3,6,7] have the probability of 1/4 to be returned (corresponding to the position of the 6s).

First, I gave O(n) time and O(n) space algorithm where I collect the set of max-indexes and then return a random number from the set. But he asked for a O(n) time and O(1) complexity program and then I came up with this.

```
int find_maxIndex(vector<int> a)
{
     max = a[0];
     max_index = 0;
     count = 0;

     for(i = 1 to a.size())
     {
         if(max < a[i])
         {
             max = a[i];
             count = 0;
         }
         if(max == a[i])
         {
              count++;
              if(rand < 1/count) //rand = a random number in the range of [0,1]
                  max_index = i;
         }
      }
      return max_index;
}
```

I gave him this solution. But my doubt is if this procedure would select one of the indexes of max numbers with equal probability. Hope I am clear.Is there any other method to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm works fine, and you can prove it via induction.

That is, assuming it works for any array of size `N`, prove it works for any array of size `N+1`.

So, given an array of size `N+1`, think of it as a sub-array of size `N` followed a new element at the end. By assumption, your algorithm uniformly selects one of the max elements of the sub-array... And then it behaves as follows:

If the new element is larger than the max of the sub-array, return that element. This is obviously correct.

If the new element is less than the max of the sub-array, return the result of the algorithm on the sub-array. Also obviously correct.

The only slightly tricky part is when the new element equals the max element of the sub-array. In this case, let the number of max elements in the sub-array be `k`. Then, by hypothesis, your algorithm selected one of them with probability `1/k`. By keeping that same element with probability `k/(k+1)`, you make the overall probability of selecting that same element equal `1/k` * `k /(k+1)` == `1/(k+1)`, as desired. You also select the last element with the same probability, so we are done.

To complete the inductive proof, just verify the algorithm works on an array of size 1. Also, for quality of implementation purposes, fix it not to crash on arrays of size zero :-)

[Update]

Incidentally, this algorithm and its proof are closely related to the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) (which I always thought was "Knuth's card-shuffling algorithm", but Wikipedia says I am behind the times).

Comment: actually this is reservoir sampling

Comment: By "keeping that same element", do you mean selecting the same max-index from the subarray, but now over the entire array?  I have doubts over its supposed probability `1/k * k/(k+1)`.  The `1/k` seems to make sense as the probability of selecting that max-index over the original subarray with `k` max elements.  However I don't understand how you get the `k/(k+1)`.  By multiplying the two probabilities, it seems the latter is supposed to refer to chance of selecting between the subarray's selection (which now represents `k` elements) and the new last max-index.  But how do you derive the math?

Comment: @onepiece: The `k/(k+1)` is just `1 - 1/(k+1)`. This code (on the "rand" line) does `max_index = i` with probability `1/(k+1)` and does nothing with probability `1 - 1/(k+1)`, which equals `k/(k+1)`. And you are right that I should have written this out.

Comment: I'm still clueless how this algorithm is correct when count actually increases during the scan. For example if `rand` is 0.5, I'd expect roughly my middle element to be chosen. If there are 5 elements, I'd expect element number 2 (0-indexed) to be chosen. As per the code though, the comparisons are (`rand < 1/1`, `rand < 1/2`, `rand < 1/3`, etc.). The first element has a higher probability of being selected (almost 50%), which leads to me think this is not uniform. Am I missing something ? If instead, this was a 2-pass algorithm where `count` is computed first, it probably makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)! There is another easy to understand solution, but requires two passes.

```
int find_maxIndex(vector<int> a){
    int count = 1;
    int maxElement = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++){
        if(a[i] == maxElement){
            count ++;
        } else if(a[i] > maxElement){
            count = 1;
            maxElement = a[i];
        }
    }
    int occurrence = rand() % count + 1;
    int occur = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        if(a[i] == maxElement){
            occur++;
            if(occur == occurrence) return i;
        }
    }
}
```

The algorithm is pretty simple, first find the number of times the max element occurs in the first pass. And choose a random occurrence and return the index of that occurrence. It takes two passes though, but very easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is sound, but the devil is in the details.

First off, what language are you using? It might make a difference. The [`rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) from C and C++ will return an integer, which isn't likely to be less than `1/count` unless it returns `0`. Even then, if `1/count` is an integer division, that result is always going to be `0`.

Also your count is off by 1. It starts as `1` when you get a new max, but you immediately increment it in the next `if` statement.

Comment: I just assumed it was meant to be pseudo-code, what with `=` being used for both assignment and comparison, `1 to a.size()`, etc. You are right that he needs `else if` instead of `if`